# Convert an string to unicode in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, hex

I need to convert a string to unicode (hex) char, I am to to do unicode to string using the below code

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",0x2665];
```

but I am not able to exactly reverse of this.

What will be the code snippet for this

Comment: You mention in a comment below that you need this for push notifications. Why? At what level with push notifications in an iOS app do you need to convert a string to a single Unicode character? You should update your question with what you really are trying to do and explain what issue you are really having.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to objective C. It has encoding methods which helps the Unicode to string and string to Unicode. Here is the sample.

```
NSString *str = @"♥";
    NSData *dataenc = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *encodevalue = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataenc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSData *data = [encodevalue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *decodevalue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",decodevalue);
```

Comment: I already did this problem is with when it is sent as notification it is displaying the unicode char itself instead of emoji (on notification banner). Because we can't decode that value in notification

Comment: you can set "alert" key when you send push notification like this: {"aps": {"alert": "High Five, bro \ue012"}}. Just append the Unicode string

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your definition of a character is. Given your example, I'd assume that `[string characterAtIndex:0]` is what you're looking for (get the first `unichar` value contained in the string, which would be 0x2665 for the string created in your first example).

However, you're getting an UTF-16 code point out of it, which may or may not be a complete logical character, and which may or may not be a complete character as printed. For instance, this will fail to represent some emojis, and will definitely fail to represent any emoji with a special skin color, or country flags. (Importantly, it can also fail to represent the characters of some languages.)

Comment: thats what the problem is I want to send push notifications with emojis for that I need this.

Comment: Use `NSString` all the way. It's not awesome but at least it won't make your task impossible by design.

Comment: NSString *str = @""; [str characterAtIndex:0] returns U+d83d u'' how to treat this value?

Comment: You can't use this value. It's not a valid Unicode character. It's only a code point that makes half of an emoji. You must use the whole NSString.

Comment: How to do that can you please help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do anymore, or what's the problem with using a `NSString*` instead of a `unichar` like you're trying to do right now.

Answer (score 1):

> custom unicode to emoji

```
#define EmojiCodeToSymbol(c) ((((0x808080F0 | (c & 0x3F000) >> 4) | (c & 0xFC0) << 10) | (c & 0x1C0000) << 18) | (c & 0x3F) << 24)

/// convert hexadecimal to unicode
/// NSString *v = omgEmojiConvertCode(@"0x1F580");
/// v is  (cannot be displayed), 

static inline NSString *omgEmojiConvertCode(NSString * code) {
    char *charCode = (char *)code.UTF8String;
    long intCode = strtol(charCode, NULL, 16);
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",intCode];

    int symbol = EmojiCodeToSymbol([s intValue]);
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&symbol length:sizeof(symbol) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return string;
}
```

> cannot be displyed is
> [image]

> now you can replace this to imageName
> [image]